# How to increase image size but not increase size container its located within

Tags: html, css

So my issue is that I am trying to decrease the amount of wasted black space in my websites header, now currently there is an image in the bottom right hand corner of the header and if I increase it's dimensions by 100px it will take up the space perfectly however when I do so, it increases the size of the header to fit the image but the blank space has just gotten bigger by the same amount.

How can I simply increase the amount of space the image will take up within the container?

Would adding sizing using CSS perhaps overwrite the HTML and make the image larger without increasing the size of the header? Please help, I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

**If increasing the size of the image also increases the size of the container: Check your `padding` on the outer element.**

Use `element{ padding:0; }` in your CSS to prevent this.

You shouldn't be "overwriting the HTML" with CSS. All styling should be done with CSS. If you set the dimensions of the container with CSS the image will fill up max space if height is set to 100%. Distortion would occur if the container is not the same aspect ratio as the image and the image takes up 100% height and width of container.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the image position:absolute and set the container position:relative